# The specific mathematical implementation of DeepLearning4J

Tags: math, deeplearning4j

I am trying to determine the exact mathematics used to train feed forward networks used for classification in deeplearning4j with stochastic gradient descent.  I have tried stepping through the code but am getting lost in the forest.

Is this documented anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

You can find it in the preOutput and backpropGradient methods in the various layers implementations:

[Here's the basic implementation used in DenseLayers](https://github.com/deeplearning4j/deeplearning4j/blob/master/deeplearning4j/deeplearning4j-nn/src/main/java/org/deeplearning4j/nn/layers/BaseLayer.java#L290)

[And the more complex convolution one used in Convolutions](https://github.com/deeplearning4j/deeplearning4j/blob/master/deeplearning4j/deeplearning4j-nn/src/main/java/org/deeplearning4j/nn/layers/convolution/ConvolutionLayer.java#L287)

The implementation might be swapped out when using CuDNN or MKL however.